# Grab following siblings in XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I am trying to grab the `li` class text in the following based on the strong tag higher up in the tree containing a certain word, in this case: "restaurants":

```
<p class="">The location, where the condo is situated, 
            offers a good choice of <strong>restaurants</strong>.
            Some of them are listed below:</p>
<ul class="">
<li class="">Restaurant 1</li>
<li class="">Restaurant 2</li>
<li class="">Restaurant 3</li>
<li class="">Restaurant 4</li>
<li class="">Restaurant 5</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried many variations of the following, assuming that I need to go higher up the tree by using "ancestors":

```
//ul/li[contains(ancestor-or-self::@strong[contains(text(),'Restaurants')])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//p[strong = 'restaurants']/following-sibling::ul[1]/li
```

will select all `li` elements of the first `ul` element following sibling of the `p` element that contains a `strong` element whose string value is `"restaurants"`.